# How do I set Nautilus/Files view preferences?

Tags: files, date, preferences

Under each file icon in the file manager, I want to see its Name, Date, and Size. (I used to have these, but have lost these since doing a reinstall today). At the present I only see the file's name.

The bottom line is that the official Ubuntu documentation for 18.04 (which I am using) here https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/nautilus-display.html.en states that I should be able to:

> "Click Files in the top bar, pick Preferences and select the Display tab."

But I have no "Files in the top bar" that I can click as shown in the screenshot!

[image]

(I can't tell you what version of Nautilus/Files I'm using, as there seems to be no "About" option -- Gotcha! -- but it's a fresh install.)

Comment: If you open a drive or select Files in the search bar you will see the Files in the top bar. Then use the drop down menu to navigate to Preferences. It also lists the About option in the same drop down menu. You can use the left win key to get to the search box.

Comment: Many thanks for trying to help, but I'm not sure I understand. I've added a screenshot so you can see what the top bar of my Nautilus/Files looks like. Is this what you mean by the "search bar"? (I usually open it with ctrl-F). I still don't see "Files in the top bar" or a drop-down menu!

Comment: Are you using the desktop version of Ubuntu and have you made any changes to it?

Comment: Your desktop should look like it is in this image: https://www.google.com/search?q=image+ubuntu+18+desktop&client=ubuntu&hs=vDj&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ_ImeluzjAhUJ8BoKHbFzD9gQ_AUIESgB&biw=1196&bih=879#imgrc=uqYZIULTjVhtDM: You can see the topbar clearly in the image

Comment: @PJK the top bar is the bar at the top of your screen, not on the window!

Comment: Oh, I get it now! I am using a dual-monitor setup, and my Nautilus window is on the right-hand monitor. While the drop-down I need is waaaaaaaaay over in the top left corner of the other monitor. That's why I did not see it. Many thanks for your patience and help :-)

Answer (score 1):

People trying Ubuntu for the first time, or switching from another flavour, may not realise, or may have forgotten (as I had) that in 18.04 the menu items that traditionally appear on the horizontal bar at the top of am *application window*, appear instead at the left of the top bar of the *whole screen*. On a multi-monitor setup, this can mean that the menu bar is nowhere near the application window, and seems to be "missing".